# Can't upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I got my new laptop Dell pre-installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I was getting started with my laptop by installing the updates. There I saw an upgrade link to Ubuntu 14.04.

The process had 4-5 steps. But during the process *installing the changes* it stopped and did not respond. So I restarted my laptop. But now it just shows blank screen followed by the Ubuntu booting process.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to backup the `/home` partition and reinstall rest of the system while keeping the `/home` partition as it is.

Next time when you do the update, see carefully that no new windows have opened, updating to another release sometimes creates new windows that prompt you to clear some stuff or what ever, but they might not appear on top of the actual upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. During initial installation, the system would have asked you to save the recovery disk. eg. flash device or disk etc. If you had done this, then use the flash device to boot. (At boot, change boot order - for me it was F12 key). You can recover either the OS or the entire disk.

But I don't know if I should upgrade to 14.04 LTS now. Whether I did something wrong or there is an inherent issue. I see lot of questions here on that.

Hope it helped.